# Why syntax highlighting is not working?

Tags: support

I have edited this question with lang tags on this question -[Zipping/archiving old log files?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/92/zipping-log-files)

As suggested here -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/168386

with `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` for XML and `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` for C#

Still I don't know why syntax highlighting is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighting has to be enabled on the site first. I went ahead and flipped it on, so those directives should work from now on.